# (org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess) NullPointerException -> java.lang.String java.io.File.getPath()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, admob, android-webview, chromium

Today first time I got strange fatal error in my firebase crash reporting:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:300)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:355)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:222)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:231)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getPath()' on a null object reference
org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess$3.doInBackground (AwBrowserProcess.java:5)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:288)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:231)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

What is interesting I don't use `webviews` in my app. The error was seen 3 times by the one user (API 21, LG-D337). *Can it be related to Firebase Ads (Admob)?*  Can I catch this error somehow?

Comment: hello were you able to resolve this? I am running into the same thing